# Pegar ip do cliente na request

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

Tenho um serviço REST na minha aplicação e nele quero pegar o IP do cliente que está fazendo a chamada, uso Spring-mvc neste projeto, aqui esta o fonte do service

```
/**
 * HttpServletRequest.
 */
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/buscar/{sessionid}/{codUsuario}")
public List<ProdutoVersaoVO> buscarProdutoCliente(
        @PathVariable("sessionid") String sessionid,
        @PathVariable("codUsuario") String codUsuario)
        throws ParseException {
System.out.println(request.getLocalAddr());
System.out.println(request.getRemoteAddr());
}
```

quando printo o ip que veio na request printa "127.0.0.1", estou invocando o serviço que está em um servidor com o ip 192.168.0.33, servidor interno so para testes mesmo e o meu ip é 192.168.0.63, faço a requisição da minha maquina logo no meu entimento deveria printar 192.168.0.62 que é o meu ip, voui postar o código do cliente que faz a requisição

```
public static List<ProdutoVersaoVO> buscarListaProdutoCliente(String usuarioId) throws IOException {
    final String sessionId = login();

    final HttpURLConnection urlConnection = getHttpUrlConnectionAreaCliente(URL_AREA_CLIENTE
            + "spring/produto/buscar/" + sessionId + "/" + usuarioId);

    urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

    final String resposta = readStringResponse(urlConnection);

    if (!resposta.isEmpty()) {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = getObjectMapper();
        return mapper.readValue(resposta, new TypeReference<List<ProdutoVersaoVO>>() {
        });
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

private static String readStringResponse(HttpURLConnection urlConnection) throws IOException {
    final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
    final StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("");
    String line = "";

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        str.append(line);
    }

    return str.toString();
}

private static HttpURLConnection getHttpUrlConnectionAreaCliente(String enderecoWeb) throws IOException {
    final URL url = new URL(enderecoWeb);
    return (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
}
```

Alguma dica de porque o ip printado é 127.0.01?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação do `getRemoteAddr`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr%28%29), se o cliente estiver sob um proxy esse método vai retornar o endereço do proxy, e não do cliente real. Como os clientes se conectam ao seu servidor? Será que o próprio Spring-MVC está agindo como proxy? (já que, nesse caso, seria o seu próprio endereço - `127.0.0.1` ou `localhost` - que seria retornado)

Se for esse o caso, talvez você consiga acessar o IP original através do header `x-forwarded-for` (ou algo similar; verifique usando [`getHeaderNames`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeaderNames%28%29)), comumente utilizado por proxies para esse fim:

```
String ipAddress = req.getHeader("x-forwarded-for");
if (ipAddress == null) {
    ipAddress = req.getHeader("X_FORWARDED_FOR");
    if (ipAddress == null){
        ipAddress = req.getRemoteAddr();
    }
}
```

[Fonte](http://www.xyzws.com/Servletfaq/how-to-get-the-client-information-in-a-servlet/0).

Comment: obrigado amigo deu certinho